# Comparing current foreground window handle

Tags: c++, c

I need to get the current foreground window handle and compare it to a saved previous window handle to see if they match, but I can't use foreground window title, because the title changes often

This is the code I'm using to compare the titles

```
char cWindow[MAX_PATH];
char nWindow[MAX_PATH];
GetWindowTextA(GetForegroundWindow(), cWindow, sizeof(cWindow));


//Later in code
GetWindowTextA(GetForegroundWindow(), cWindow, sizeof(cWindow));
if (strcmp(nWindow, cWindow) != 0)
{
    fputs("found!",file);
    strcpy(nWindow, cWindow);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to check whether the foreground window has changed, you should compare the *window handles* directly, without their titles.

```
HWND oldForegroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

HWND newForegroundWindow = GetForegrundWindow();
if (newForegroundWindow != oldForegroundWindow) {
  ForegroundWindowHasChanged(oldForegroundWindow, nForegroundWindow);
  oldForegroundWindow = newForeroundWindow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Errr you are NOT setting nWindow to anything both your calls are setting cWindow. Do you think that may be an issue?

Comment: I changed the first one to 
        GetWindowTextA(GetForegroundWindow(), nWindow, sizeof(nWindow)); 
and still have the same problem

Comment: suggest that you do the following:  after the first GetWindowTextA put a fprintf(file, "found nWindow to be: %s\n", nWindow); and after the second one you put fprintf(file, "found cWindow to be: %s\n", cWindow); and see where it takes you (also what is the value of file?)